# Can't use relative name for Django app

Tags: django, django-apps, django-1.8

I have a fresh Django 1.8 project called *test1*. I'm provided with an app named *smartmetadata* that I want to use. I've copied it on **test1/test1/apps/smartmetadata** and I've included `url(r'^smartmetadata/', include('smartmetadata.urls'), name='smartmetadata'),` in the **test1/urls.py** file.

When including it in `INSTALLED_APPS` as `smartmetadata` I get `ImportError: No module named smartmetadata`. However, if I include it as `test1.apps.smartmetadata` then it loads correctly. I've seen in other projects like [Mayan](https://github.com/mayan-edms/mayan-edms/blob/master/mayan/settings/development.py) that apps are included using only their own label and not the complete path. How can I achieve that?

**Edit**: My complete **urls.py** file content:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'test1.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^smartmetadata/', include('smartmetadata.urls'), name='smartmetadata'),
]
```

My complete project tree:

```
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── run.sh
└── test1
    ├── apps
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   └── smartmetadata
    │       ├── admin.py
    │       ├── forms.py
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── __init__.pyc
    │       ├── models.py
    │       ├── models.pyc
    │       ├── tests.py
    │       ├── utils.py
    │       └── views.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    ├── settings.pyc
    ├── urls.py
    ├── wsgi.py
    └── wsgi.pyc
```

Comment: Are you importing that module in the file urls.py?

Comment: No, I'm not. I didn't see that other projects do that. If you could point me, for instance, how Mayan does it, it would be great.

Comment: Can you paste here your full urls.py file and your project tree structure?

Comment: With all the files/folders you have inside smartmetadata app

Comment: I've included it in the OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `apps` folder to your `PYTHON_PATH`.

`settings.py` is a fine place to do it:

```
import os
import sys

# BASE_DIR should already be present in your settings.
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

APPS_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'apps')

sys.path.append(APPS_DIR)
```

By the way, I would recommend putting the apps folder at the root of your project (i.e. `BASE_DIR`) instead of in the "settings" folder.

Comment: Here: https://github.com/mayan-edms/mayan-edms/blob/master/mayan/settings/base.py#L20 and here: https://github.com/mayan-edms/mayan-edms/blob/master/mayan/settings/base.py#L189
The reason is not only styling, it kept the path to the apps in the migrations flat which helped integrate 3rd party commercial apps into Mayan